# Tcl regular expression - copying all matches to list

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to use the simple code to find matches from the text file that look like this
| 259.937 MB/s|
I just want the number part. I've tested the regex using online regex debugger's and it seems to work but when I test it out I'm not getting anything printed in the list

```
set fp [open "logfile.log" r]
set bandwidth [regex -inline {(\d{3}\.\d{3})\sMB\/s\|}  $fp -> bandwidth]

puts "The contents of the list is: $bandwidth"
close $fp
```

I'm also not sure if the list is a list embedded within a list, meaning the outer list contains the matches and the inner list contains the total and sub matches per match.. But I would prefer to just have the sub match if that's possible.

Comment: You have to be careful with online regex testing tools: they are usually using PCRE or Java/Javascript flavours. Tcl regexes [have their own syntax](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) that has some unique features.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've got is that you're by using a submatch variable *and* the `-inline` option together, a combination which probably ought to be an error. Instead, do this (without `-inline`):

```
if {[regex {(\d{3}\.\d{3})\sMB\/s\|}  $fp -> bandwidth]} {
    puts "The contents of the list is: $bandwidth"
} else {
    puts "Nothing was found"
}
```

or this (with `-all` *as well as* `-inline`):

```
set matches [regex -all -inline {(\d{3}\.\d{3})\sMB\/s\|} $fp]
if {[llength $matches]} {
    puts "The full contents of the list is: $matches"
    foreach {-> bandwidth} $matches {
        puts "Found $bandwidth"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize the iteration across submatches was possible as you wrote out in the second example. Much appreciated. Someday I too hope to spread the knowledge like you are doing!

Answer (score 0):

You're matching against the file *handle*, not the file *contents*.

With this data:

```sh
$ cat logfile.log
a | b | 123.456 MB/s| c
d | e | 789.012 MB/s| f
```

Either read the whole file into a variable and search with `[regexp -all]`,

```
set fp [open logfile.log]
set data [read $fp]
close $fp
# this one uses a lookahead and no capturing parentheses
# which makes the "-inline" list contain only the wanted data
regexp -all -inline {\d{3}\.\d{3}(?= MB/s\|)} $data
# => {123.456 789.012}
```

or iterate over the lines of the file.

```
set fp [open "logfile.log" r]
while {[gets $fp line] != -1} {
  if {[regex {(\d{3}\.\d{3})\sMB\/s\|}  $line -> bandwidth]} {
    lappend found $bandwidth
  }
}
close $fp
puts $found  ;# => 123.456 789.012
```